# getting output with weird text like☻

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hey! I am getting a problem with my script.

I wrote it when reading [LPTHW](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/) book.

I am not getting an error message but I am not getting the correct output, I think there might be a setting wrong with my system. I am confused.

Here is the script:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv


print "We're going to erase %r." % filename
print "If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "If you do want that, hit RETURN."

raw_input("?")

print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'w+')

print "Truncating the file. Goodbye!"
target.truncate()

print "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

line1= raw_input("line1: ")
line2= raw_input("line2: ")
line3= raw_input("line3: ")

print "I'm going to write these to the file."

target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")

print "Now, I am going to read the file"
print target.read()

print "And finally, we close it."
target.close()
```

and here is the output:

```
PS C:\Users\Isaac\lpthw> python ex1.py sample.txt
We're going to erase 'sample.txt'.
If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C).
If you do want that, hit RETURN.
?
Opening the file...
Truncating the file. Goodbye!
Now I'm going to ask you for three lines.
line1: i
line2: love
line3: mo
I'm going to write these to the file.
Now, I am going to read the file
#☻    ` ▬☻    ` ▬☻      .☻
```

Comment: If you want to erase and rewrite the file, why not just open it with `open(filename, 'w')` instead of worrying about truncating it?

Comment: @DavidRobinson that would give an IOError at `target.read()`.

Comment: @lvc: Right, right. It just seems like a bit odd, but of course it's possible that this is necessary (rewrite the start of a file, leave the rest intact).

Answer (score 6):

When you call `target.write()`, the file pointer is left just after the written data. You can call `target.tell()` to see where it is:

```
>>> target.tell()
0
>>> target.write('hello')
>>> target.tell()
5
```

You need to seek to the beginning of the file before you read it:

```
target.seek(0)
print target.read()
```

Comment: @isa On my system it returns an empty string, which is what I would expect. It might be a Windows thing; I don't have a Windows box to test with at the moment